# SQL Developer compiler log disappeared

Tags: sql, oracle

I've recently been trying to compile several procedures and it all worked great, the compiler showed errors, I fixed them. All was working perfectly.

Except I accidentally clicked "x" instead of minimizing the compiler log tab and now it just won't show up again. I've tried Ctrl shift L, View > Log and nothing. So I'm not entirely sure what happened to it and I really need a fix for it to show messages/errors

Comment: Click a `View` option in the main menu, and then click `Log` option in a submenu. The log window should appear on the screen.

Comment: We tried that but it still doesn't show up

Answer (score 2):

We fixed it. Go into C:\Users\your user\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system[version]\o.ide.[numbers]. There you will find a file called windowinglayoutdefauld.xml, you can delete that, restart SQL Developer and all settings will go back to default, with your compiler log!

Answer (score 0):

A visual manual how to close and restore the compiler log window in Oracle SQL-Developer.
[image]

[image]

---

Click View/Log

[image]

---

And compiler window appears again

[image]

Comment: First pic is what happened on accident and we did do all that, it just didn't want to show up at all. I posted a solution to this below by deleting the winwowinglayoutdefault.xml file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Next time try the menu item "**Window > Reset Windows To Factory Settings**"